# Weather app for freeCodeCamp, code isn't working in codepen.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I am making weather app for free code camp, its working fine on my laptop (used notepad++ and firefox, didn't work on chrome) except its not changing background image(first problem), second: when I put my code in codepen it didn't work at all. Please help. Below is the link to my pen:

https://codepen.io/Rits_Verma/pen/mEKxrE?editors=1111

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Local Weather Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!--<script src="test.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="sc.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->

     <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/css/weather-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/font" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400,400italic|Radley|Tangerine" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1><i class="wi wi-day-rain-mix"></i> Weather App</h1>
            </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h1><span class="city"></span></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <h1 class="toggle"><a href="#"><span class="temp"></a></span></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center">
                <h1><span class="clouds"></span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
         Coded with  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-heart fa-spin" style = "color:red;font-size:24px;"></i>  by <a href="https://twitter.com/RituSkVerma" target="_blank">RITU</a>
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    background-size: cover;}
.jumbotron {
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        color:#f6f8f9;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        .btn {
            padding: 0.5em;
        }
    }
}
.jumbotron h1{
    color:#f6f8f9;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    font:18px;
}

 footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
  /* padding: 2px 0 4px 0; */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;

}
footer a{
    color:white;
}

a {
    color:#f6f8f9;
    text-decoration:  none !important;
}

a:active {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:  none !important;

}
a:visited {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:  none !important;
}
a:hover {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:  none !important;
}

/*media queries */
/* 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 670px; 
    background-size: cover;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    background-size: cover;}
}
 */
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        /* $("body").css("background-image", "url('img/giphy.gif')"); */


        var lattitude;
        var longitude;
         var toggleC = true;
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lattitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    /* $("#data").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    */console.log("lat "+lattitude);

    var api='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lattitude+'&lon='+longitude+'&appid=518b05d055aad92f54e053f3b2221c12';
    console.log(api);
    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var weatherType=data.weather[0].description;
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        var celcius = Math.round(kelvin-273.15);
        var fahren = Math.round(kelvin*(9/5)-459.67);
        var city=data.name;
        /* var cl=data.clouds.all; */

        console.log("Hello "+weatherType);
            /* console.log("city "+city);
            console.log("temp "+celcius);
            console.log("temp "+fahren); */
            console.log("temp "+data.main);
        $('.city').text(city);
        $('.temp').text(fahren+'\xB0'+" F");



        $('.clouds').text(weatherType);
        $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
            if (toggleC == true) {
              toggleC = false;
              $('.temp').text(fahren + '\xB0' + " F");
            } else if (toggleC == false) {
              toggleC = true;
              $('.temp').text(celcius +'\xB0' +" C");
                }
        });


        if(weatherType=="clear sky" ||"calm") {

               $("body").css({"backgroundImage": "url('img/resort-863129.jpg')","backgroundRepeat":"no-repeat"}); 
              $("a").css("color","black"); 
        }

        else if(weatherType=="scattered clouds" ||"few clouds"||"broken clouds" ||"overcast clouds") {

              $("body").css({"backgroundImage": "url('img/pigs-and-garden-011.jpg')"}); 
            $("a").css("color","black"); 
        }

        else if(weatherType=="shower rain" || "light intensity shower rain" ||"ragged shower rain"||"light rain"||"light intensity drizzle" ||"drizzle" ||"heavy intensity drizzle" ||"light intensity drizzle rain "||"drizzle rain" ||"heavy intensity drizzle rain" ||"shower rain and drizzle" || "heavy shower rain and drizzle" || "shower drizzle" ||"light intensity shower rain" ||"heavy intensity shower rain") {
            $("body").css({"backgroundImage": "url('img/gif___running_through_the_rain_by_turst67-d6scius.gif')","backgroundRepeat":"no-repeat"});
        }
        else if(weatherType=="very heavy rain" ||"moderate rain"||"heavy intensity rain" ||"very heavy rain" ||"extreme rain" ||"freezing rain" ||"heavy intensity shower rain") {
            $("body").css({"backgroundImage": "url('img/rain-758107.jpg')"});
        }
        else if(weatherType=="thunderstorm" ||"light thunderstorm" ||"heavy thunderstorm"||"ragged thunderstorm") {

            $("body").css("background-image","url('img/giphy (1).gif')");
            $("h1,h2").css("color","white");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="thunderstorm with rain" ||"thunderstorm with light rain" ||"thunderstorm with heavy rain" || "thunderstorm with light drizzle" ||"thunderstorm with drizzle" || "thunderstorm with heavy drizzle") {
            $("body").css("background-image", "url('img/maxresdefault.jpg')");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="snow" ||"light snow"||"heavy snow"||"sleet"||"shower sleet"||"light rain and snow"||"rain and snow"||"light shower snow"||"shower snow" ||"heavy shower snow") {
            $("body").css({"backgroundImage": "url('img/crystals-335429.jpg')","backgroundRepeat":"no-repeat","backgroundPosition":"fixed center bottom no-repeat"});
            $("a").css({"color":"#161d24"});
        }
        else if(weatherType=="mist" ||"smoke" || "haze" || "sand,dust whirls"||"fog"||"sand"||"dust"|| "volcanic ash" ||"squalls") {
            $("body").css("background-image", "url('img/mist.jpg')");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="tornado" ||"tropical storm") {
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/thunderstorm_an.gif)");
            $("h1").css("color","#f6f8f9");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="hurricane"||" severe gale" ||"violent storm"){
            $("body").css("background-image","url(img/hurricane.gif)");
            $("h1").css("color","#f6f8f9");
        }

        else if(weatherType=="hot"){
            $("body").css("background-image","url(img/sunset-473345.jpg)");
            $("a").css("color","black");

        }
        else if(weatherType=="windy"){
            $("body").css("background-image","url(img/grass-354737.jpg)")
            $("h1").css("color","#f6f8f9");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="light breeze") {
            $("body").css("background-image","url(img/sunset-731307.jpg)")
            $("h1").css("color","black");
        }
        else if(weatherType=="fresh breeze" ||"gentle breeze" ||"moderate breeze") {
            $("body").css("background-image","url(img/grass-520912_1920.jpg)")
            $("h1").css("color","#f6f8f9");
        }
         else {
            $("body").css("background-image","url('img/sunrise-1292301_1920.jpg')","backgroundRepeat","no-repeat","backgroundPosition","fixed center bottom no-repeat");
        } 


  });
     });

    }

    });
```

Comment: Check out the console: is because the https issues. Codepen works on https while openweathermap on http, so the browser refuses to load insecure (http) content. You can load codepen with http, but then Chrome (not sure other browsers) refuses to get the location because of the insecure origin.

Comment: I modified the url of open weather app and now its working in codepen, here is the modified url:   var api='https://crossorigin.me/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lattitude+'&lon='+longitude+'&appid=518b05d055aad92f54e053f3b2221c12';     and here is the link of working codepen https://codepen.io/Rits_Verma/pen/mEKxrE?editors=1111 but still I am not able to change background image, please help!

Comment: Neat trick. For background try changing every `if(weatherType=="scattered clouds" ||"few clouds"||"broken clouds" ||"overcast clouds")` to like `if(weatherType=="scattered clouds" || weatherType=="few clouds"|| weatherType=="broken clouds" ||weatherType=="overcast clouds")`. When you use `||` options aren`t connected between, so you have to compare both again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution, its not working :(

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXjNzb Also another one with different location(hardcoded lat/long) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKBpZx

Comment: for some reason it wasn't working earlier, now working fine, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Here is the full working code https://codepen.io/Rits_Verma/full/mEKxrE/